# Convert query from sql type in mongodb type

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, postgresql, pymongo

I am working in python with pymongo.
I have a query in psql that looks like this :

```
cursor.execute("select id13 from nc_durhamallwithorder where date2 >='2010-01-01' and date2<='2011-01-01'"),
```

Now i want to convert that query in mongodb type.
I did something like this

```
cursor=mycol1.find({"$and": [ { "date2": { "$gte": "2010-01-01" } }, { "date2": { "$lte":"2011-01-01" } } ]  } )
```

This works fine but i want to select only id13

I thought something like this:

```
cursor=mycol1.find({"id13":1},{"$and": [ { "date2": { "$gte": "2010-01-01" } }, { "date2": { "$lte":"2011-01-01" } } ]  } )
```

But it doesnt work.Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pass a second argument with a dict and the fields you want to keep

```
mycol1.find({"$and": [ 
        { "date2": { "$gte": "2010-01-01" } }, 
        { "date2": { "$lte":"2011-01-01" } } 
    ]},
    {"id13":1} 
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I am executing query with cursor so i did cursor=mycol1.find({"$and": [
        { "date2": { "$gte": "2010-01-01" } },
        { "date2": { "$lte":"2011-01-01" } }
    ]}
).fields(id13=1) and the output says :AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'fields'

Comment: I edited my question.I only added cursor function

Comment: Oh my bad, it's pymongo. I updatef my answer for your package

Comment: Now it works great.Thank you!If you have time i want to ask you one more thing.My date2 field is a string type.Why $gte and $lte work fine without date2 being double?

Comment: You're welcome. Since the dates are stored year-month-day...  In this format, the alphabetical order will be the same as the chronological order.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66447922/how-to-convert-a-whole-column-from-string-type-to-date-type-in-mongodb-with-pymo

Comment: if you have spare time please check this out